# GridView in not showing data

Tags: java, android

I am testing GridView for my project.so far so good but the gridview is not showing any data please guide me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView msgTV;
    GridView msgGV;
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter;
    static final String[] items={"data-0","data-1","data-2","data-3","data-4",
                                    "data-5","data-6","data-7","data-8","data-9"
                                };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initGUI();
        msgGV.setAdapter(adapter);
            }



    private void initGUI()
    {
        msgTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        msgGV=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.displayGridView);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    }

}
```

follwoing is from my layout file
Does ther is something wrong in column width or spacing

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/displayGridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:columnWidth="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
        </GridView>
```

Comment: Any exception you are getting ?

Comment: not at all.Just data is not there in emulator everything else is ok

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of what the device is showing? Your xml wouldn't hurt either (just to make sure you haven't done anything silly like setting the visibility to GONE)

Comment: try setting background as black  
android:background="#000000"

Comment: I set it black,blue and orange but to no effect.

Comment: Could you post the entire xml file? I guess your textview is occupying the entire space and there is no space for the grid!

Comment: try increasing the columnWidth

Comment: No i set different colors for both textview and gridview and both are there in emulator just data is not there

Comment: Rajesh sir is right i increased it to 100 and it worked but why it that?thanks rajesh sir

Comment: I think it's because of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` have some default padding which is more than 5px.